# Vue command not found

Tags: node.js, macos, vue.js, npm, vue-cli

Trying to install Vue, but I am getting an error `-bash: vue: command not found`.

Everything is installed per Vue instructions and I'm not sure why I am getting this issue.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Screenshot of an error]

Comment: Use npx `npx @vue/cli create myapp`

Comment: @onmyway133
thanks, your command works for me and it saves my times and life.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Try updating your PATH variable with this command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Users/denis/.npm-global/bin
```

Updating Node/NPM might help too.

Comment: Also... Be sure and restart the terminal after you update the path

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: This one helped!

Comment: It worked, thank you.

Comment: Thanks, solved for MAC (Mojave).

Comment: It's not worked for me with node v10.15.3

Comment: Use: npx @vue/cli create myapp

Comment: On Windows, add "C:\Users\{Username}\AppData\Roaming\npm"  to system path

Comment: Thanks!.. Fixed my issue.

Comment: Weird everyone has helped this answer useful, is that even a Linux path? /Users/... ? How has this helped? Probably it's on Mac? On Linux I ran `npm root -g` and finally found its binary file in this path: `/usr/local/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin`.

Comment: @aderchox This question is macos specific implied by questions tags and provided screenshot

Comment: This also works if you're using yarn e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:/home/<user>/.yarn/bin`

Comment: If you are using windows and yarn - adding this to the PATH variable should do the trick: C:\Users\--user--\AppData\Local\Yarn\bin , just change "user" part to the name of your user

Answer (score 21):

It is better to uninstall the Vue with the command: `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli` and then install again.

Comment: I tried, not worked

Comment: It worked for me when I installed with "-g"

Comment: export PATH="$(yarn global bin):$PATH"

Comment: @heithemmoumni yes, that was it for me, npm install linked the package correctly, yarn install didn't