# -bash : vue: command not found

Tags: vue.js, npm, macos-high-sierra, vue-cli-3

I'm trying to install vue-cli with npm but I always get this error `-bash : vue: command not found` when I check the version.

I've tried everything, uninstall and install again, I check here [Vue command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51957631/vue-command-not-found) , but it still doesn't work.

Error :

`iMac-de-stage02:~ stage02$ vue --version
-bash: vue: command not found`

I installed vue-cli with :
`npm install -g @vue/cli`

[image vue-cli installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tl4dL.png)

My node version :
`v10.15.3`

My npm version : 
`6.9.0`

when I run `npm bin` : 
`/Users/stage02/node_modules/.bin`

OS :
`mac high sierra version 10.13.6`

I also tried with `yarn` but nothing changed.
Thanks in advance for your answer.

Comment: could you add a snippet showing the exact error you get?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you checked if `/Users/stage02/node_modules/.bin` is in your `$PATH`? Try `echo $PATH` to see if it's in there.

If it's not, open `/etc/paths` and add the path on a new line.

Comment: Yes it is in my `$PATH`, my `echo $PATH` return : `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/stage02/node_modules/.bin`

Comment: I add an image for the installation on my post. I think my path is false.

Comment: Looks like it's linking `/Users/stage02/.node_modules_global/bin` to where the vue-cli is installed, so it should be this path that should be in the `$PATH`